# Indent a string by 4 spaces (Add Tab to string)

Tags: string, vb.net

I am trying to add indentation to a string, essentially adding 4 spaces in front of each line in the string. The string that I want to add the indentation to is called `StringToIndent`.

```vb
Public Class ModifyPage
    Private Sub Button_Test_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button_Test.Click
        Dim StringToIndent As String = ("This is the first row
This is the second row
    This is the third and final row in MyString")

        Dim MySecondString As String = "This is a string in one line."
        Dim BothStringsTogether = StringToIndent & Environment.NewLine & MySecondString

        Debug.Write(BothStringsTogether)
    End Sub
End Class
```

The current output:

```html
This is the first row
This is the second row
    This is the third and final row in MyString
This is a string in one line.
```

I want the final code (that is indented) to output:

```html
    This is the first row
    This is the second row
        This is the third and final row in MyString
This is a string in one line.
```

How can this be achieved through code? Is there a formatting option that allows me to add indentation? A method that doesn't require me to loop through a string and adding four spaces for each line would be preferable.

Edit: A way to achieve the expected output is to replace the new line with a new line and then add the indent. However, there must be a more elegant way of doing it?

Code:

```vb
        Dim StringToIndent As String = ("This is the first row
This is the second row
    This is the third and final row in MyString")

        Dim indentAmount = 4
        Dim indent = New String(" "c, indentAmount)
        StringToIndent = indent & StringToIndent.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine & indent)

        Debug.Write(StringToIndent)
```

Comment: "A more elegant way"?  Your code does exactly what you're asking, adds an indention (though it also adds the indentation after the last line if that line ends in the NewLine - that may not be what you want). You'll need to define what "more elegant" is or means. Your code example is compact, concise and readable - that would meet my general rules for "elegant".

Comment: [String.PadLeft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netframework-4.8) Method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
Dim res as String
Dim parts As String() = StringToIndent.Split(ControlChars.CrLf.ToCharArray)
For Each part As String In parts
    res.Append("    ") & part & vbCrLf
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# you can mark the String as a verbatim string literal by prefixing the literal with the `@` symbol.

In VB.NET we don't have this option. Instead, a workaround would be to create an XML literal and get the value. Here is an example:

```
    Dim input As String = <element>    This is the first row
This is the second row
    This is the third and final row in MyString
This is a string in one line.
                          </element>.Value().ToString()

Debugger.WriteLine(input.ToString())
```

If the value is not static, e.g. you're getting it from somewhere, then you're forced to iterate through the String in some form. You can either Replace like in your example, do a Split and Join (similar to your example), or you'll need to manually iterate.

The manual iteration could *look* more elegant using LINQ, but you don't gain anything from it.

The bottom line is that if your String is static then you can use the XML literal example I provided, otherwise if the String is dynamic then your solution is perfectly appropriate.

**UPDATE**
As Andrew Morton pointed out, multiple line String literals have existed since Visual Studio 2017. The following would produce the same outcome as my XML literal example:

```
Dim input As String = "    This is the first row
    This is the second row
        This is a string in one line"

Debugger.WriteLine(input)
```

Comment: Multi-line string literals exist in VB.NET nowadays, since at least VS2017.

Comment: @AndrewMorton that's good to know, I wasn't aware of that. I'll update my response.

Answer (score 1):

Using an interpolated string indicated by the $ preceeding the string and the vb constants.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim s = $"{vbTab}This Is the first row{vbCrLf}{vbTab}This Is the second row{vbCrLf}{vbTab}{vbTab}This Is the third And final row in MyString{vbCrLf}This Is a string in one line."
    Debug.Print(s)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this into an extension method to use for building "readable" SQL commands for debugging and logging errors. I've added some `Optional` parameters to the method to allow for things like `.Trim`ming an individual line of text of extra spaces before indenting, as well as handling single- or multi-line strings as defined by the caller:

```
    <DebuggerStepThrough>
    <Extension()>
    Public Function Indent(ByVal Text As String, ByVal IndentLevel As Integer,
                           Optional ByVal IndentCharacter As Char = " "c,
                           Optional ByVal MultiLine As Boolean = False,
                           Optional ByVal TrimLineText As Boolean = False) As String
        Dim CurrentIndent As New String(IndentCharacter, IndentLevel)
        Dim IndentedString As String = String.Empty

        If MultiLine Then
            Dim TextParts As String() = Text.Split({ControlChars.Cr, ControlChars.Lf, ControlChars.CrLf}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            For I As Integer = 0 To TextParts.Count - 1
                If TrimLineText Then
                    IndentedString += CurrentIndent & TextParts(I).Trim
                Else
                    IndentedString += CurrentIndent & TextParts(I)
                End If

                If I < TextParts.Count - 1 Then
                    IndentedString += Environment.NewLine
                End If
            Next I
        Else
            IndentedString = Text.Replace(ControlChars.Cr, " "c)
            IndentedString = IndentedString.Replace(ControlChars.Lf, " "c)
            IndentedString = IndentedString.Replace(ControlChars.CrLf, " "c)

            If TrimLineText Then
                IndentedString = IndentedString.Trim
            End If

            IndentedString = CurrentIndent & IndentedString
        End If

        Return IndentedString
    End Function
```

This way, I can call it on any string value and get a "pretty" version for reading and/or printing:

```
Dim MyString As String

MyString = "        This is a string in one line ".Indent(2, ControlChars.Tab, False, True)

' results in
' [TAB][TAB]This is a string in one line
' and

MyString = "    This is a string in one line ".Indent(2, ControlChars.Tab, False, False)

' produces
' [TAB][TAB][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE][SPACE]This is a string in one line[SPACE]
' ^.Indent ^^From the original string  ^ 
' and

MyString = "    This is the first row
    This is the second row
        This is the third and final row in MyString".Indent(1, ControlChars.Tab, True, True)

' gives me
' [TAB]This is the first row[CrLf]
' [TAB]This is the second row[CrLf]
' [TAB]This is the third and final row in MyString
```

As you can see, setting the `TrimLineText` parameter to `False` preserves the leading and trailing spaces. This, IMO, gives a somewhat misleading result. Still, I thought it better to give the caller the *option* to have the method "clean up" the string than to force it on them and give a totally unexpected result.